# @font-face fonts unloading when switching applications/tabs

Tags: font-face

Generally speaking my font works fine but I'm seeing on odd occasions such as switching back to the browser from another application and sometimes when switching back from another tabs that my font seems to have unloaded and is using the fallback font.

I'm struggling to consistently replicate this and when I have seen it there are no errors.

I have also seen this happen in Chrome and Firefox on windows and osx and at a bit of a loss as to how this can be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this issue in Firefox personally, but it is a known bug in Chrome.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336170